# I want to create custom filter,when true, data.status: 'yes' only repeat,when false, 'yes' and ' no' repeat by using custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

[demo](http://codepen.io/kenjimorita/pen/NqZpGx?editors=101)

### I want to create custom filter,when true, data.status: 'yes' only repeat,when false, 'yes' and ' no' repeat by using custom filter

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="SampleController as c">
 <input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="checked">
 <label for="check" ng-init="checked=true">only yes , toggle yes & no</label>
 <div>filter list </div>
 <div>
  <div>from get ServiceFunction</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-if="checked" ng-repeat="fafa in c.getedService.data">
      <!-- Service list-->
      {{fafa.namae}}
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Make demo, no one interested in that kind of questions, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry demo is here http://codepen.io/kenjimorita/pen/NqZpGx?editors=101

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @christopher I am reading now

Answer (score 0):

Just small spelling mistake in using `ng-model`, You used `mg-model` instead `ng-model`. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojvKyd?editors=101) is the working codepen.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you. I did not notice. The next my problem, propertye. data.status is no at the time of false,when true,I want to display  key'yes' &' no' of value to view thank you

Comment: maybe I have to use lodash.js??